phpMailer -- image not showing in email
I want a logo to appear in the emails sent, but they do not.  The alt tag does show.  I have looked at several sites on addEmbeddedImage and they all seem to follow the same pattern.  Similarly in the Body tag.  Do I have the two tags in the right place?  Should one or both be in the **while
** statement along with $mail->send(); ?
I've tried using hard coding and string coding in the **addEmbeddedImage **tag but it doesn't seem to matter.  Please help with coding instead of forwarding me to some other discussion (BTW: that probably does not help most users).
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("images/wncwasmall.jpg","logo","wncwasmall.jpg", "image/jpg" );

    //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = '<center><img alt="WNCWA Logo" src="cid:logo"></center>' . $message; 

    //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('email@wncwa.net', 'WNCWA'); 
        $mail->addReplyTo($replyto, $sender);   //Reply to sender email
        $mail->addAddress($from_email, $sender);  //copy sent to sender



    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Connect to database -- connection is PDO
     $sql= $conn->prepare("
          SELECT fname, lname, email 
          FROM test
          ORDER BY lname
     ");

     $sql->execute(); 
     while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {  

          $fname= $row['fname']; 
          $lname= $row['lname']; 
          $to= $row['email'];

          $mail->addAddress($to, $subject); 
          $mail->send();

          $mail->clearAddresses() ;

      if($mail->send()) {} 
        else {echo "<div style='color:red;' >NOT sent - $fname $lname <br /></div> "; }

        }  // close while
    } // close try


You're not checking whether the call to addEmbeddedImage() actually works; it could be failing due to an incorrect path or permissions. If it's being included, it should be obvious if you enable debug output with $mail->SMTPDebug = 2.

Unrelated to your problem (probably), when I see the // close try without the opening, I tend to assume you have one giant try block which is just asking for trouble, especially when the interior holds a loop, and even more so when interacting with multiple services (email and database). The code is not wrong, but the potential for hiding a bug is great. I see your table is named test, so hopefully this will be addressed in the future, although if you are developing/testing something, I’d also recommend letting the exceptions rise up now.

"Please help with coding instead of forwarding me to some other discussion" - we are not a coding writing service, and we are also all volunteers here. If someone provides you with code, that’s great. If someone recommends that you look at another answer, please accept that it is in good faith trying to guide you. If you ask a question and it is closed as a duplicate, you can ask for clarification and it might be reopened.
